# How to release memory for UIImageView (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I got a problem with UIImage. I've manually added UIImageView objects to a scroll view. The problem is : when I have more than 50 images, memory will increase to around 200MB, and the app will be crash on iphone 4 or 4s. I want to release memory for images that is not in visible part when I receive Memory Warning to prevent crashing but I don't know how to release them with Swift. Help me please.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadImage(index:Int){
if self.imgPaths.count == 0 {
    println("Has not data")
    actInd.stopAnimating()
    return
}
var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: self.imgPaths[index].stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))!
let width:CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width
let height:CGFloat = self.view.bounds.height
var view:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));

if let imgObj = self.dicData[index] {

}
else
{
println("imgURL \(imgURL)")
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let imgItem = UIImage(data: data)!

        var te :Float = self.imgPaths.count > 0 ? Float(index  + 1) / Float(self.imgPaths.count) : 1
        self.progressView.setProgress(te, animated: true)

        if let imgObj = self.dicData[index] {

            if index < self.imgPaths.count - 1
            {
                var nextIndex:Int = index + 1
                self.loadImage(nextIndex)
            }
            if(index == self.imgPaths.count - 1)
            {
                if self.currentImageIndex > 0
                {
                    self.isAddedFirstImg = true
                }
                if !self.isAddedFirstImg
                {
                    self.scrollViews[0].zoomScale = self.zoomScales[0]
                    self.view.insertSubview(self.scrollViews[0], belowSubview: self.tabBar.viewWithTag(77)!)
                    self.isAddedFirstImg = true
                }

                self.actInd.stopAnimating()
                println("loaded image")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.dicData[index] = UIImageView(image: imgItem)

            self.dicData[index]?.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), size:imgItem.size)

            // 2
            self.scrollViews[index].addSubview(self.dicData[index]!)
            self.scrollViews[index].contentSize = imgItem.size

            // 3
            var doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "scrollViewDoubleTapped:")
            doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
            doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            self.scrollViews[index].addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)

            var singleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "scrollViewSingleTapped:")
            singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            self.scrollViews[index].addGestureRecognizer(singleTapRecognizer)

            var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
            swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
            self.scrollViews[index].addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

            var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
            swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
            self.scrollViews[index].addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

            // 4
            var scrollViewFrame = self.scrollViews[index].frame
            var scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollViews[index].contentSize.width
            var scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollViews[index].contentSize.height
            var minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
            self.zoomScales[index] = minScale
            self.scrollViews[index].minimumZoomScale = minScale

            // 5
            self.scrollViews[index].maximumZoomScale = 1.0
            self.scrollViews[index].delegate = self

            // 6
            self.centerScrollViewContents(index)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                println("downloaded image index: \(index) CH.\(self.chapterID)")
                if(index == 0)
                {
                    self.scrollViews[0].zoomScale = self.zoomScales[0]
                    self.view.insertSubview(self.scrollViews[0], belowSubview: self.tabBar.viewWithTag(77)!)
                    self.actInd.stopAnimating()
                }

                if index < self.imgPaths.count - 1 && !self.stopDownload
                {
                    var nextIndex:Int = index + 1
                    self.loadImage(nextIndex)
                }
                if(index == self.imgPaths.count - 1)
                {
                    if self.currentImageIndex > 0
                    {
                        self.isAddedFirstImg = true
                    }
                    if !self.isAddedFirstImg
                    {
                        self.scrollViews[0].zoomScale = self.zoomScales[0]
                        self.view.insertSubview(self.scrollViews[0], belowSubview: self.tabBar.viewWithTag(77)!)
                        self.isAddedFirstImg = true
                    }

                    self.actInd.stopAnimating()
                    println("loaded image")
                }
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
}
```

}

Comment: If I were you I would use a collectionView instead of a scrollView since visible cells will be dequeued to save memory. You can configure the photo in cell for row at indexPath and then page your request for images.

Comment: @Dare I also need to zoom the image so I used scrollView. Is it possible to zoom in collection View ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift uses ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) to manage memory.  To free something from memory, you must remove all references to that object.  ARC maintains a count of the number of places that hold a reference to the object, and when that count reaches 0, the memory is freed.

In your case, your imageViews are stored in `self.dicData[index]` and they are added as subviews of `self.scrollViews[index]`.  You will need to remove the imageView from its superview and from `self.dicData`.  Once you do that, the memory will be freed.

If you have the `index` of the imageView you want to free:

```
self.dicData[index]?.removeFromSuperview()
self.dicData[index] = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift there is really good tool called "lazy"
you might wanted to study about lazy var its very handy when it comes down to the images and tableview (for your instance collectionview)

you will see a huge difference when its used from custom cell. 
create a imageview e.g. lazy var imageViewer:UIImageView
my app was at about 150mb 200mb memory now its at 40~60mb try it!